# How to deploy a deep learning model in Flask (Python)?

Tags: python, deep-learning, machine-learning-model, computer-vision

I am still an amateur with respect to deploying deep learning models as a flask app. I want to deploy a VQA model based on [MMF](https://mmf.sh/docs) (Pythia) in a flask app. [Github repository for reference.](https://github.com/facebookresearch/mmf)
 Can someone explain in brief as to how to go about it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a simple web application with one endpoint. I've checked the mmf doc you can load a model using it's keys:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from mmf.common.registry import registry

model_cls = registry.get_model_class("<DESIRED_MODEL_KEY">)
model = model_cls.from_pretrained("<DESIRED_PRETRAINED_ZOO_KEY>")

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    data = request.get_data()
    prediction = model(data)
    return jsonify(list(prediction))

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

I haven't ran that code but I know for a fact that this won't run out of the box. `data` is a dictionary and you need to get the right key and convert the value
to a numpy array or Torch tensor. And `predict` will be a numpy array (or Torch tensor - but can be converted back to numpy) and you will need to convert everything back to a standard python format (because numpy or torch data types are not json serialisable).